# Перенос строк в jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

```
$('#id').text('**text1**\n**text2**\n**text3**');//при клике на кнопку
<span id="id"></span>
```

Но всё-равно строки не переносит, хотя и \n не показывает. Выводит просто
text1text2text3
Что я не так делаю?

Comment: там где text1 text2 text3 - без звёздочек

Comment: Это же html, тут нужен `<br>`, разве нет?

Comment: это html, а не документ, для переносов в html нужен тег <br>

Comment: HTML не выводит переносы строк. Для этого есть тэг <br/>. Оберните в тег pre и они должны появиться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В HTML для переноса строк вместо \n используется тег `<br>`. Чтобы в элемент можно было вставить тег не как обычный текст, метод text() нужно заменить на html():

```
$('#id').html('**text1**<br>**text2**<br>**text3**');//при клике на кнопку
<span id="id"></span>
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы \n тоже отображался как перенос строки, используйте CSS-свойство `white-space:pre` (такое поведение по умолчанию установлено у `<pre>`):

```
$('#id').text('**text1**\n**text2**\n**text3**');//при клике на кнопку
<span id="id" style="white-space:pre"></span>
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что в первом варианте будет перенос строк при помощи br?

Comment: @Cheg пардон, упустил из вида. Вместо text() нужно html(), сейчас исправлю ответ